# On Windows, how shall I call arbitrary ACPI methods?

Tags: windows, windows-10, acpi

On Linux, the module `acpi_call` enables this, however I don't see such a thing on Windows. Is it possible through WMI ? Or do I really need to write some kernel mode code ?

Note that I'm speaking of methods that *already exist*, it's not about defining new methods.

As an example, suppose I want to call `\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF`, how shall I do this ?

**EDIT :** Without any equivalent to `acpi_call` in Windows, it seems the only remaining method is enabling kernel debugging and start a debugging session like it's mentioned in [the MS docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-local-kernel-debugging-of-a-single-computer-manually).

However, that requires disabling Secure Boot, which is normal, but not a viable option when it should be done on a regular basis.

Actually, I'm not even sure the Windows framework would easily permit writing an `acpi_call` equivalent, since it seems [drivers can only evaluate control methods that are child objects of the device in the ACPI device tree](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/acpi/evaluating-acpi-control-methods), hence an equivalent would have to be attached to the root of the device tree. The `Acpi.sys` driver being already there, I suspect a conflict would arise.

### Limiting the scope to one device

Evaluating `\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF` actually corresponds to powering off my laptop's Nvidia dGPU. The same problem applies, since the Nvidia driver is already attached to `\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP` in the ACPI device tree. So writing a device driver at that same place would likely conflict.

Thankfully (if I may say so) there's a reason why I want to do this, it's because my dGPU is dead. Being dead the driver doesn't load any more, and doesn't bother managing the device's power status. So I could remove or disable the Nvidia driver and replace it with a driver that would only power off the device during system startup.

That being said, I don't know how to write such a simple driver.

Hence as long as I'm correct, I have two options :

1. Configure the Nvidia driver in such a way that it powers off the device all by itself.
2. Write a device driver that does the job, replacing the Nvidia driver.

Advices are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

Some ACPI methods can be accessed through *powercfg*. For example, to generate a report on battery status and use and send it to c:\Windows\System32, enter the following in a CMD prompt as Administrator:

```
powercfg /BATTERYREPORT
```

[Microsoft documents the *powercfg* command set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options) but I don't see one to disable the GPU. To do that, you might need to install Microsoft's [Windows Device Console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon), *devcon.exe*, or a free third-party tool, Nirsoft's [DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html).

To use *devcon* to disable the GPU, enter the following in CMD,

```
devcon.exe disable "Name of GPU as Shown in Device Manager"
```

And. of course, use *enable* to use the GPU again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I noticed MS advises _not_ to use devcon, and use _PnPUtil_ instead. Hence, shouldn't I use PnPUtil ? Moreover, wouldn't passing the name of the GPU in the device manager to `devcon.exe` simply do the exact same thing as right-clicking the device and choose _Disable_ in the device manager, which afaik doesn't shut it down at all, but only disables the driver ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so, but from kernel driver only - and then access the driver from your user-mode app.
You can read about it into [MSDN article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/acpi/evaluating-acpi-control-methods).

GitHub has some examples of this kind of drivers, check [this](https://github.com/kdshk/WindowsHwAccess) for example.

Another issue - kernel driver should be signed by EV sign (costly every year).

Comment: Thanks for replying ! I bought a new laptop in the meantime, but this information can still be useful. However, I’m worried about the EV sign requirement, I mean, it makes sense for a driver that’s distributed for general use, but in the case of sofware for local use only (only on my computer), shouldn’t it be enough to add a personal key in the Secure Boot database and sign with it ? Note it’s primarily a matter of being able to run what I want on my own system without having to refer to an external authority. Money comes second here…

Comment: No, personal key is enough for "test mode" only (and secure boot should be disabled, however, you need to select test mode boot after every restart).
Thanks, MS, for so "Friendly" approach!
I'm forced using hack-load as a result (i use ACPI calls for hardware control into one of mine GitHub projects)...

Comment: Being able to run whatever code one wants to run without having to ask for anyone else’s permission can be part of a normal setup, that shouldn’t be forbidden. This is a serious issue, and I’m afraid not many people are aware of this…

Comment: Some outsource developers using their corporate keys, some pay, some leave this issue to user (test mode start).
Some, like me, use hack methods (well-known from XP time...)